# Batch Script to Open TXT doc - My Documents path for any user

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

**Hello!**

***Hopefully an easy one***

Can I input a path for a text file within a batch script that will recognise the path regardless of the windows user that executes it?

E.g. I've tried:

```
@echo off
Path c:\documents and settings\%user%\My Documents
start Test.txt 
exit
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `%user%` with `%username%` should do the trick.

Comment: Also probably adding a backslash after 'My Documents' (just in case it saves OP some extra time).

Comment: So close...Yet so far! - Cheers for your help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any user.

```
@echo off
Path %USERPROFILE%\My Documents
start Test.txt 
exit
```

%USERPROFILE% refers to (in my case) C:\Users\Administrator\ 
%USERNAME% Only refers to (in my case) Administrator

Answer (score 0):

There are some built-in environemt variables that point to certain path in windows - where `%username%` is the current user:

```
%userprofile% - usually C:\Users\%username%
%SYSTEMROOT%  / %WINDIR% - c:\windows - but you need admin permissions to write here
%SYSTEMDRIVE% / %HOMEDRIVE% - c:
%TEMP%\%TMP% - C:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Temp
%ProgramData%    -  C:\ProgramData needs admin permissions
%ProgramFiles%   -  C:\Program Files  needs admin permsissions
%LOCALAPPDATA%   -  C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local
%HOMEPATH%  - \Users\%username% - its without system drive
%CommonProgramFiles% - C:\Program Files\Common Files
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%    -  C:\ProgramData
%APPDATA%    -  C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming
%USERPROFILE%   - %SystemDrive%\Users\%username%
```

In your case the best you can use is `%userprofile%\documents` for vista and above (or `%userprofile%\My Documents` for XP\Win2003)